# How to create controller, model , helper inside a ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

This is the first time I'm trying to build a gem. I use `bundle gem MyGem`

there are three directories inside MyGem. `bin lib MyGem`. I want to create `controller` `model`, `helper` inside it I tried `scaffold` but didn't worked for me any idea !!!

Comment: please look into rails engin

Comment: What do you try to achieve? Can you elaborate? What will be the purpose of the gem? How should it be used? Who will use it (community vs. a few internal users)?

Comment: @spickermann It will be for our internal projects, the gem will will dealing with database and all ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Rails [Engines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) instead of a gem, which can include controllers, models, helpers, routes and other Rails elements.